# flutter bluetooth list only devices owned by me

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, esp32

I am making a device controlled via bluetooth with esp32 using the flutter_bluetooth_serial package. When the paired devices are listed, I want only my esp32 device to appear in the list. How can I achieve this?

My code where the devices are listed

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

class BluetoothDevices extends StatelessWidget {
  const BluetoothDevices({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bluetooth Devices'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.getBondedDevices(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<BluetoothDevice> devices = snapshot.requireData;
            if (devices.isNotEmpty) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: devices.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(devices[index].name ?? 'Unknown device'),
                    subtitle: Text(devices[index].address),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(devices[index]);
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('No devices found'),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```